# Missing c/c++ unit testing support in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing

I am using the *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers* (2021-03) package and cannot find the entry "C/C++
Unit Testing Support" under "Help > Install New Software".

I need it for using gtest with a C++ project but the installation entry in the software menu (within Programming Languages) does not exist anymore. Previous versions appeared to have it available. I followed this guide: https://www.pbma.de/docpt/content/951f7999aa405c4c016c1cda35f564d08ae7c71bf867722ad896d11c21e3be51

Is it removed from there or how can I install it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have it installed? If you have the "hide items that are already installed" check box selected it won't be shown in the list if it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out the package was already installed and therefore hidden.
To get the gtest library to work additional steps were required as descriped in the guide.